# PDF viewer combined with video player

Tags: pdf, video-player

I need to give a PDF presentation but I want to include some videos in between some of the slides.

Is there a PDF viewer which will allow me to play videos in between slides for a presentation?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: There is now [a very good community wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer) about this at TeX stackexchange : [How to include multimedia files in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use latex-beamer. you can install it if it's not usig:

```
sudo apt-get install latex-beamer
```

you can get the official documentation of beamer from [here](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

This [tex question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations) would help you to achieve that

To view the ouput pdf you can use [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/), you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

Read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163089/okular-to-play-embedded-videos-in-beamer) also, this would help

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that. I actually made it work, but Adobe reader kept crashing randomly while playing the video. That's the last thing I want to happen during my presentation, so I was looking for a robust solution which doesn't require fancy addons to my pdf file.

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: It's already do, check the links provided above

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. I also tried the tutorial here (http://abarry.org/the-new-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/) and it worked as well, but I had to install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` as shown here (http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html)

Comment: That's good, glad to help and thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works on Ubuntu 14.04, but I will outline another solution as given [here](http://abarry.org/the-new-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/).

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libgstreamer0.10-dev libgee-dev valac-0.16 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev librsvg2-dev libpoppler-glib-dev libgtk2.0-dev
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

git clone https://github.com/davvil/pdfpc.git
cd pdfpc
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Then include the video in beamer like so:

```
\href{run:myvideo.avi?autostart&loop}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth,height=0.5625\paperwidth]{myposter.jpg}}
```

And open the pdf like so:

```
pdfpc presentation.pdf
```

`pdfpc` is nice for giving presentations as it includes things like a timer and a dual output for two displays, one for controls, one for the projector output. As far as I can tell, it is stable and doesn't crash.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pdfpc` works in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: +1 for the great `pdfpc`.